# Modify suffix of file created using S3 Multipart file upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonrdsouza/f2c77dedb8d80faebcf9) script for creating multipart file upload. The resultant file has name myfilename.csv-0. I want to get rid of -0 in the file name. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This was being added in the script ("{}-{}".format(result_filepath, i)). I removed i and it is generating the file as expected.